# C fgets() - Only last line of the file is written to array?

Tags: c, fgets

I have a really weird problem with fgets() in C. Below is the code I'm working with.

```
FILE* conf_file;
char array[20];
conf_file=fopen("configuration","r");
if (!conf_file) printf("There is not conf file");
while(!feof(conf_file)){
    // if( feof(conf_file)) break;
    fgets(array,20,conf_file);
    //printf("%s",array);
    if (!read_id_flag){
        labris_id=atoi(array);
        read_id_flag=1;
        printf("%d\n",id);
        continue;
    }
    protocol_array[protocol_index]=array;
    // printf("%s %s",array,protocol_array[protocol_index]);
    protocol_index++;
}
int i;
for(i=0;i<10;i++){
    printf("%s",protocol_array[i]);
}
fclose(conf_file);
```

Well, in the while scope if I try to print the `protocol_array` it works perfectly. But if I try to print the array after the while scope, it prints only the last line of the array, 6 times (6 is number of lines in the file).

Any idea is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Comment: `char array[20]; protocol_array[protocol_index]=array;` that's the problem.

Comment: I thought I did. Sorry for that. Some guy indented it for me. ;)

Comment: @KarolyHorvath What is wrong with that? I mean it is a static array, and inside the while scope the array gets a line in a time, and I can put it in the `protocol_array`. But below the scope it doesn't work.

Comment: Show the definition of `protocol_array`. Chances are you are assigning a pointer to the same `array` six times. That's why you get the same content after the loop - all your elements in `protocol_array` are pointing to the same `array`!

Comment: `protocol_array` declaration:  char* protocol_array[];

Comment: If `protocol_array` is `char * protocol_array[]` then you can consider `protocol_array[protocol_index]=strdup(array);` or some `malloc` family + `strcpy` family combination with `\0` termination for each char array (as you are treating it as *C string*). Don't forget to `free` them when you are done with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`char* protocol_array[];` can't contain any data directly, other than a pointer to the allocated memory.

You should either define `protocol_array` as `char protocol_array[20][6];`, allocating storage for 6 lines of string with length 20 and strcpy like this:

```
char protocol_array[20][6];
//...
strcpy( protocol_array[protocol_index], array );
```

or allocate the memory via `malloc`:

```
char** protocol_array = malloc( 6 * sizeof( char* ) );
//...
protocol_array[protocol_index] = malloc( strlen(array)+1 );
strcpy( protocol_array[protocol_index], array );
```

Note that in the latter case you should `free` any allocated memory when you're done with it:

```
for( i = 0; i<protocol_index; ++i )
    free( protocol_array[i] );
free( protocol_array );
```

Answer (score 0):

protocol_array[protocol_index]=array; - This line seems to be the problem. You should do a strcpy.

If you keep assigning, array each time, only the address of array (which is a local array) gets stored in all the elements of protocol_array. As evident from your code, the last read line will be present in the "array" and since all elements of protocol_array points to address of "array", it just prints that for all elements.

Comment: But, if you are going to do a strcpy, then you should also have some memory allocated for each element of protocol_array. If your protocol array is char *protocol_array[], then it needs memory allocation for each element. Be careful with that.